# Votação em estrela com input radio, javascript/css

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estou criando um formulário de cadastro, nele irei inserir um sistema de votação, queria fazer que ao clicar em alguma estrela, as outras anteriores irão mudar de cor também. (Segue o código que criei)

```
<div class="vote">
<label>
    <input type="radio" id="cm_star" name="fb" value="1" />
    <i class="fa"></i>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" id="cm_star" name="fb" value="2" />
    <i class="fa"></i>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" id="cm_star" name="fb" value="3" />
    <i class="fa"></i>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" id="cm_star" name="fb" value="4" />
    <i class="fa"></i>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" id="cm_star" name="fb" value="5" />
    <i class="fa"></i>
</label>
```

O resultado em imagem:

[image]

Comment: Qual é o problema que está enfrentando? o que falta para funcionar?

Comment: Sugiro você utilizar um plugin para isso, é mais fácil do que fazer do zero. esses aqui por exemplo. https://css-tricks.com/star-ratings/,  http://speckyboy.com/2010/04/21/15-javascript-and-plugins-and-tutorials-for-adding-ratings/,  http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-rating-plugins/, http://wbotelhos.com/raty

Comment: Quero que ao em qualquer estrela, as anteriores mudassem de cores também, tipo, clica na 4 estrela a 3, 2 e 1 também mudassem de cor.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

É possível fazer utilizando somente CSS, com o seletor irmão `~` e algumas modificações no HTML.

```css
.estrelas input[type=radio] {
  display: none;
}
.estrelas label i.fa:before {
  content:'\f005';
  color: #FC0;
}
.estrelas input[type=radio]:checked ~ label i.fa:before {
  color: #CCC;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="estrelas">
  <input type="radio" id="cm_star-empty" name="fb" value="" checked/>
  <label for="cm_star-1"><i class="fa"></i></label>
  <input type="radio" id="cm_star-1" name="fb" value="1"/>
  <label for="cm_star-2"><i class="fa"></i></label>
  <input type="radio" id="cm_star-2" name="fb" value="2"/>
  <label for="cm_star-3"><i class="fa"></i></label>
  <input type="radio" id="cm_star-3" name="fb" value="3"/>
  <label for="cm_star-4"><i class="fa"></i></label>
  <input type="radio" id="cm_star-4" name="fb" value="4"/>
  <label for="cm_star-5"><i class="fa"></i></label>
  <input type="radio" id="cm_star-5" name="fb" value="5"/>
</div>
```

Nota: foi necessário incluir um radio vazio pré-selecionado para que as estrelas sejam exibidas corretamente quando nenhum valor está selecionado.

Comment: Sanção, ele gostaria que as estrelas anteriores também fiquem selecionadas.

Comment: @MaiconCarraro, só vi agora os comentários, tomei como base a imagem na pergunta, obrigado por avisar

Comment: @MaiconCarraro resposta atualizada

Comment: Muito bom ! :))

Comment: Muito obrigado, era isso mesmo o que eu tava precisando =D

Comment: Muito legal Sanção! + 1

Comment: No me navegador não está aparecendo as estrelas, quando uso o código acima.

Comment: Gostei, me ajudou!

Answer (score 6):

Fiz usando javascript puro, basicamente criei uma função pra percorrer todas `img` com mesmo nome e conforme qual estrela foi clicada (indice) eu atribuo se ela vai ser destaca ou não.

```js
function seleciona(name, indice) {
   var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img[name=' + name + ']');
  
   for (var i=0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
       if (i <= indice)
           imgs[i].className = "destaque";
       else
           imgs[i].className = "apagada";
   }
}

window.onload = function() {
   var imgs = document.querySelectorAll('img[name=fb]');
  
   for (var i=0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
       (function(name, i) {
          imgs[i].addEventListener('click', function () {
              seleciona(name, i);
          });
       })(imgs[i].name, i);
   }
}
```

```css
.apagada {
  background-image: url('http://www.biblecast.net.br/resources/estrela-prata.png');
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.destaque {
  background-image: url('http://imobiliariacincoestrelas.com.br/images/estrela.png');
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<label>
    <img name="fb" class="apagada"/>
</label>
<label>
    <img name="fb" class="apagada"/>
</label>
<label>
    <img name="fb" class="apagada"/>
</label>
<label>
    <img name="fb" class="apagada"/>
</label>
<label>
    <img name="fb" class="apagada"/>
</label>
```

Answer (score 5):

Seguindo sua estrutura HTML, deixo aqui uma sugestão utilizando jQuery.

```js
$('.vote label i.fa').on('click mouseover',function(){
    // remove classe ativa de todas as estrelas
    $('.vote label i.fa').removeClass('active');
    // pegar o valor do input da estrela clicada
    var val = $(this).prev('input').val();
    //percorrer todas as estrelas
    $('.vote label i.fa').each(function(){
        /* checar de o valor clicado é menor ou igual do input atual
        *  se sim, adicionar classe active
        */
        var $input = $(this).prev('input');
        if($input.val() <= val){
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
    $("#voto").html(val); // somente para teste
});
//Ao sair da div vote
$('.vote').mouseleave(function(){
    //pegar o valor clicado
    var val = $(this).find('input:checked').val();
    //se nenhum foi clicado remover classe de todos
    if(val == undefined ){
        $('.vote label i.fa').removeClass('active');
    } else { 
        //percorrer todas as estrelas
        $('.vote label i.fa').each(function(){
            /* Testar o input atual do laço com o valor clicado
            *  se maior, remover classe, senão adicionar classe
            */
            var $input = $(this).prev('input');
            if($input.val() > val){
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
        });
    }
    $("#voto").html(val); // somente para teste
});
```

```css
.vote label {
    cursor:pointer;
}
.vote label input{
    display:none;
}
.vote label i {
    font-family:FontAwesome;
    font-size:18px;
    -webkit-transition-property:color, text;
    -webkit-transition-duration: .2s, .2s;
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in;
    -moz-transition-property:color, text;
    -moz-transition-duration:.2s;
    -moz-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in;
    -o-transition-property:color, text;
    -o-transition-duration:.2s;
    -o-transition-timing-function: linear, ease-in;
}
.vote label i:before {
    content:'\f005';
}
.vote label i.active {
    color:gold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="vote">
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="fb" value="1" />
    <i class="fa"></i>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="fb" value="2" />
    <i class="fa"></i>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="fb" value="3" />
    <i class="fa"></i>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="fb" value="4" />
    <i class="fa"></i>
</label>
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="fb" value="5" />
    <i class="fa"></i>
</label>
</div>

<div id="voto">
    
</div>
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jw262pnw/)**

Comment: Bem interessante a solução usando `content` e `mouseover`, mas vou deixar minha resposta caso alguém queira fazer mais "manual"

Comment: @MaiconCarraro com certeza sua resposta é válida, e ainda é em javascript puro, se ele unir as ideias conseguirá chegar ao resultado que deseja.