# como preencher as estrelas de um star rating?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Como fazer para preencher as estrelas de um "star rating".

O cálculo aparentemente está funcionado. Dando um "echo" na variável `$calc` o resultado é exibido. Exemplo, se a nota for **3.3**, ele deve preencher 3 estrelas e 30% da 4 estrela do rating.

**A dúvida é:** onde devo colocar esta variável para que seja exibido como  estrelas?

#### Código HTML

```
  <form id="rating" action"rating.php" method="post">
   <input type="hidden" name="id" id="idd" value="<?php $idprod?>" />
    <div class="vote">
     <label>
      <input id="stars" class="radioo" type="radio" name="fb" value="1" />
      <i class="fa" id="fa"></i>
     </label>
     <label>
      <input id="stars" class="radioo" type="radio" name="fb" value="2" />
      <i class="fa" id="fa"></i>
     </label>
     <label>
      <input id="stars" class="radioo" type="radio" name="fb" value="3" />
      <i class="fa" id="fa"></i>
     </label>
     <label>
      <input id="stars" class="radioo" type="radio" name="fb" value="4" />
      <i class="fa" id="fa"></i>
     </label>
     <label>
      <input id="stars" class="radioo" type="radio" name="fb" value="5" />
      <i class="fa" id="fa"></i>
     </label>
   </div>
```

#### JavaScript (jQuery)

```
$('.vote label i.fa').on('click mouseover',function(){
    // remove classe ativa de todas as estrelas
    $('.vote label i.fa').removeClass('active');
    // pegar o valor do input da estrela clicada
    var val = $(this).prev('input').val();
    //percorrer todas as estrelas
    $('.vote label i.fa').each(function(){
        /* checar de o valor clicado é menor ou igual do input atual
        *  se sim, adicionar classe active
        */
        var $input = $(this).prev('input');
        if($input.val() <= val){
            $(this).addClass('active');
        }
    });
    $("#voto").html(val); // somente para teste
});
//Ao sair da div vote
$('.vote').mouseleave(function(){
    //pegar o valor clicado
    var val = $(this).find('input:checked').val();
    //se nenhum foi clicado remover classe de todos
    if(val == undefined ){
        $('.vote label i.fa').removeClass('active');
    } else { 
        //percorrer todas as estrelas
        $('.vote label i.fa').each(function(){
            /* Testar o input atual do laço com o valor clicado
            *  se maior, remover classe, senão adicionar classe
            */
            var $input = $(this).prev('input');
            if($input.val() > val){
                $(this).removeClass('active');
            } else {
                $(this).addClass('active');
            }
        });
    }
    $("#voto").html(val); // somente para teste
});
```

#### Consulta em PHP

```
$id = $_GET['cod'];
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id_produto = $id");
$test = mysql_query("SELECT votos, pontos FROM produtos WHERE id_produto = $id");
$aux = mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$idprod = $aux['id_produto'];
$row = mysql_fetch_array($test);
$voto = $row['votos'];
$ponto = $row['pontos'];
//saída do rating (pontuação)
$calc = round(($ponto/$voto),1);
```

Comment: O que você já tem feito quanto ao código? Edite a sua pergunta com o código, se possível poste o nome da biblioteca JavaScript que utilizou.

Comment: jquery a biblioteca vou postar o jquery aqui que faz tipo de um hover com o mouse enter e mouse leave

Comment: editei a pergunta

Comment: Ainda falta o PHP

Comment: eu to editando o php calma ai

Comment: relacionado: [Votação em estrela com input radio, javascript/css](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/70502/13561)

Comment: Seu código HTML está quebrado, é melhor revisar isso.

Comment: o desse exemplo amigo ele so marca pro click as estrelas e tambem nao insina colocar para preencher com os votos no meu ja esta tudo pronto ele marca com a cor gold quando vc preenche 5 estrelas mas agora eu quero que ele pegue o resultado da divisao e preencha as estrelas de acordo com isso para ela ter a nota

Comment: http://plugins.krajee.com/star-rating/demo tem um monte aqui.

Comment: Você poderia por exemplo usar o `Math.round()` para arredondar seu número e marcar a estrela correspondente

Comment: pensa comigo nem toda divisao ira retornar um numero inteiro por isso preferi usar o round ai com aquele,1 eu pego 1 casa depois da virgula

Comment: tipo assim como que eu posso fazer uma barra de progresso que fica escondida atras dos icons e quando ela pega a variavel calc e tem um resultado essa variavel ela faz como se fosse uma barra de progresso por traz dos icons dando um efeito de preenchimento nas estrelas como posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 1):

A questão é que você tem uma nota de 1 a 5, ao que tudo indica, neste sentido, se a nota é 3, você teria que fazer um checkbox no input número 3:

```
<input id="stars" class="radioo" type="radio" name="fb" value="3"<?php echo ($calc == 3) ? ' checked="checked"' : '';?>/>
```

O jQuery irá fazer o evento onLoad, baseado neste elemento, atribuindo um active para a classe de onde há um valor computado do input:
percorrendo as classes: `.vote label i.fa`:

Seria:`<i class="fa active" id="fa"></i>`

Então, acredito que não há necessidade de mantê-la ativa manualmente, mas se não for o caso, basta fazer o mesmo:

```
 <i class="fa<?php echo ($calc == 3) ? ' active' : '';?>" id="fa"></i>
```

Comment: pelo o que estou vendo nesse codigo nao ficaria do modo que eu queria e os numeros quebrados? como faco exemplo 4.8 ele so vai me preencher 4 estrelas? nao seria mais facil fazer uma classe tipo full com um background amarelo e ela ser mostrada de acordo com os calculos?

Comment: ou tipo jogar uma cor na fa mesmo mas ela tem que preencher de acordo nao so numeros inteiros isto que quero fazer

Comment: star rating sempre usará número inteiro, para fazer outras escalas decimais, use barra de porcentagem. O que você pode é distribuir sua pontuação entre esses números de 1 a 5. algo do tipo: `if ($nota  <= 1 ) { $rating = 1 } elseif( $nota <= 2 && $nota > 1 ) { $rating = 2} ...`

Comment: mas minha pontuacao nao esta de 1 a 5? se eu tiver uma pontuacao 10 em determinado produto ai eu tenho 3 pessoas que votaram eu nao terei que fazer pontuacao/pessoas? nisso dara um numero vai dar 3.3 com o meu exemplo mas vamus supor que de 3.6 eu vou dar 3 estrelas naquele produto irei ignorar o .6?

Comment: por isso o if... 1 a 5  = 1 a 10

Comment: Por exemplo, se você tem notas de 0-10, vc teria grupo de 0(sem estrela), 1-2 (1 estrela), 3-4 (2  estrelas), 5-6(3  estrelas),7-8(4  estrelas),9-10(5  estrelas).

Comment: nao cara as notas variam elas iram aumentar no exemplo eu fiz com 10 mas se outra pessoa dar 3 estrelas para ela ela vai aumentar a pontuacao vai para 13 e o numero de votos 4

Comment: Então se o número é quebrado, use o jRate.

Comment: Tem essa opção tabém, ele preenche só parte das estrelas: https://rateit.codeplex.com/ olha o exemplo: http://www.radioactivethinking.com/rateit/example/example.htm